Exodus 14:23 - The Death of Pharaoh and the Singular Grammar Used
Exodus 14:23

And the Egyptians pursued and went after them into the midst of the sea, all Pharaoh’s horses, his chariots, and his horsemen.

What is the grammatical reason for the plurality of Pharaoh's horse and chariot when according to the interlinear these are in the singular? Based on the Hebrew, shouldn't this verse read:

And the Egyptians pursued and went after them into the midst of the sea, all, Pharaoh’s horse, his chariot and his horsemen.




Strong's
Hebrew
English
Morphology




7291 [e]
וַיִּרְדְּפ֤וּway-yir-də-p̄ū
And pursued
Conj-w | V-Qal-ConsecImperf-3mp


4713 [e]
מִצְרַ֙יִם֙miṣ-ra-yim
Egypt
N-proper-fs


935 [e]
וַיָּבֹ֣אוּway-yā-ḇō-’ū
and went
Conj-w | V-Qal-ConsecImperf-3mp


310 [e]
אַחֲרֵיהֶ֔ם’a-ḥă-rê-hem,
after them
Prep | 3mp


3605 [e]
כֹּ֚לkōl
all
N-msc


5483 [e]
ס֣וּסsūs
horses
N-msc


6547 [e]
פַּרְעֹ֔הpar-‘ōh,
of Pharaoh
N-proper-ms


7393 [e]
רִכְבּ֖וֹriḵ-bōw
his chariots
N-msc | 3ms


6571 [e]
וּפָרָשָׁ֑יוū-p̄ā-rā-šāw;
and his horsemen
Conj-w | N-mpc | 3ms


413 [e]
אֶל־’el-
Into
Prep


8432 [e]
תּ֖וֹךְtō-wḵ
the midst
N-msc


3220 [e]
הַיָּֽם׃hay-yām.
of the sea
Art | N-ms



Source: BibleHub—Hebrew Text Analysis

The Hebrew text in question (Exodus 14:23):

וַיִּרְדְּפוּ מִצְרַיִם וַיָּבֹאוּ אַחֲרֵיהֶם כֹּל סוּס פַּרְעֹה רִכְבּוֹ וּפָרָשָׁיו אֶל־תּוֹךְ הַיָּם׃

The verbs in this verse (לרדוף and לבוא) are in the 3rd person plural past tense. Further, the nouns you're referring to are preceded by the indefinite pronoun כל which indicates their plurality. It's a sound translation decision to render horse, chariot, and rider in their plural forms in English since every bit of surrounding context indicates this was a pursuing army.

You should also note Pharaoh as ruler of all Egypt in a legal sense possessed all the horses, chariots, and riders who he took in his attempt to reclaim the Israelites and the mixed multitude who left with them.

Is it possible for this to be translated in the singular, or grammatically does it HAVE to be plural for horse and chariot. My thought is if this was singular, it would seem to end the long held debate as to whether Pharaoh went into into sea and drowned.

@KatieRoseMüller thoroughly a translation philosophy question: a wooden/literalist translation could plausibly keep the cardinality of the Hebrew. Essentialist translations would probably lean towards clarity. I don't think anything in the text demands one approach over the other

Amenhotep II was the Pharaoh of the Exodus and he didn't die in the sea in pursuit.
